# Pandas Pivot Table: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'CustomFieldOption' and 'CustomFieldOption'

Tags: python, pandas

I retrieve data from an internal database, save it as a Pandas data frame, then pivot the data frame.  I'm getting an error that appears to be related to differences in data types.  I've spent hours trying to debug this, but with no luck.  Here is the full code:

```
from jira import JIRA
import pandas as pd

cert_path = 'C:\\cert.crt'

start_date = '2020-10-01'
end_date = '2020-10-31'

# three different instances (each with their own schema)
a_session = JIRA(server='https://jira.myinstance-A.com', options={'verify': cert_path}, kerberos=True)

b_session = JIRA(server='https://jira.myinstance-B.com', options={'verify': cert_path}, kerberos=True)

c_session = JIRA(server='https://jira.myinstance-C.com', options={'verify': cert_path}, kerberos=True)


# define Jira queries
query_1 = 'project = \"Test Project 1\" and issuetype = Incident and resolution = Resolved and updated >= {} and updated <= {}'.format(start_date, end_date)

query_2 = 'project = \"Test Project 2\" and issuetype = Incident and resolution = Resolved and updated >= {} and updated <= {}'.format(start_date, end_date)

query_3 = 'project = \"Test Project 3\" and issuetype = Defect and resolution = Resolved and releasedate >= {} and releasedate <= {}'.format(start_date, end_date)

query_4 = 'project = \"Test Project 4\" and issuetype = Enhancement and resolution = Done and completed >= {} and completed <= {}'.format(start_date, end_date)


# fetch all issues from a given session for a given query
block_size = 100
block_num = 0


def get_all_issues(session, query):

    block_size = 50
    block_num = 0
    
    start = 0
    all_issues = []
    while True:
        issues = session.search_issues(query, start, block_size)
        if len(issues) == 0:
            # No more issues
            break
        start += len(issues)
        for issue in issues:
            all_issues.append(issue)

    issues = pd.DataFrame(issues)

    for issue in all_issues:
        d = {
            'jira_key' : issue.key,
            'issue_type' : issue.fields.type,
            'creator' : issue.fields.creator,
            'resolution' : issue.fields.resolution
             }

        fields = issue.fields  # For brevity
        if hasattr(fields, "custom_field_123"):
            d['system_change'] = fields.custom_field_123
        if hasattr(fields, "custom_field_456"):
            d['system_resources'] = fields.custom_field_456
        if hasattr(fields, "custom_field_789"):
            d['system_backup'] = fields.custom_field_789

        issues = issues.append(d, ignore_index=True)

    return issues


# list of queries, and the corresponding backend
queries = [
    (a_session, query_1),
    (a_session, query_2),
    (b_session, query_3),
    (c_session, query_4),
]


# loop over each pair of session and query, calling the get_all_issues function, and save the dataframe we get each time
dataframes = []

for session, query in queries:
    dataframe = get_all_issues(session, query)
    dataframes.append(dataframe)


# concatenate all data frames
df_concat = pd.concat(dataframes)

# derive the business units from the project codes
df_concat['business_unit'] = np.where(df_concat['jira_key'].str.contains('MER'), 'Mercedes',
                             np.where(df_concat['jira_key'].str.contains('HON'), 'Honda',
                             np.where(df_concat['jira_key'].str.contains('AST'), 'Aston Martin', '*ERROR*')))
```

The `df_concat` data frame prints out as follows:

```
   jira key   issue_type    creator   resolution   system_change   system_resources   system_backup   business_unit
0  MER-361    Incident      Smith, J  Resolved     Saturn          High               NaN             Mercedes
1  MER-362    Enhancement   Jones, T  In Progress  NaN             Medium             Not Applicable  Mercedes
2  MER-363    Incident      Ng, V     Resolved     Saturn          NaN                Not Applicable  Mercedes
3  MER-364    Incident      Jones, T  Resolved     NaN             NaN                Not Applicable  Mercedes
0  AST-022    Incident      Smith, J  Resolved     Saturn          High               NaN             Astin Martin
1  AST-023    Incident      Smith, J  Resolved     Saturn          High               NaN             Astin Martin
2  AST-024    Incident      Jones, T  Resolved     Saturn          High               NaN             Astin Martin
0  HON-124    Incident      Smith, J  In Progress  NaN             Low                NaN             Honda
1  HON-125    Incident      Smith, J  Resolved     Saturn          High               NaN             Honda
2  HIN-126    Incident      Jones, T  In Progress  Saturn          Low                NaN             Honda
```

## Notice how the index changes in the data frame.

The goal is to apply a Pandas pivot table to the `df_concat` data frame:

```
# first, fill replace all of the Nan values with empty strings:
df_all = df_all.fillna('')


# then, ensure the columns are cast to strings   
df_concat['business_unit'].astype('str')
df_concat['system_change'].astype('str')


# finally, pivot the data
pivot = pd.pivot_table(data=df_concat, index='business_unit', columns='system_change'), values='jira_key, aggfunc='size')

pivot
```

I see the following error message:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'CustomFieldOption' and 'CustomFieldOption'
```

I thought that maybe the error relates to the custom fields.  But, that doesn't seem to be the case.

I tested with the following:

Test # 1:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(data=df_concat, index='creator', columns='issue_type'), values='jira_key, aggfunc='size')
```

Results in:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'User' and 'User'
```

Test # 2:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(data=df_concat, index='creator', columns='issue_type'), values='jira_key, aggfunc='size')
```

Results in:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'User' and 'User'
```

Test # 3:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(data=df_concat, index='resolution', columns='issue_type'), values='jira_key, aggfunc='size')
```

Results in:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Resolution' and 'Resolution'
```

Test # 4:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(data=df_concat, index='creator', columns='resolution'), values='jira_key, aggfunc='size')
```

Results in:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'User' and 'User'
```

I replaced all of the `NaN` values with empty strings and cast the `business_unit` and `system_changes` columns to strings.

On the production data, I also did the following:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing

encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit_transform(df_all['creator'].astype(str))
encoder.fit_transform(df_all['resolution'].astype(str))
```

I see:

```
array([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

I'm not sure why this `'<' not supported between instances of...` error is being raised.  Maybe there is an issue with the index (it starts anew each time a data frame is concatenated), but I'm not sure how to debug this further.  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!